# Can't access docker via SSH (Azure DevOps)

Tags: docker, azure-devops

Last docker installed on VM in Azure.

When I'm connected to it via putty(SSH) this works:

**docker -v**

When I try to do this during release and SSH job ("Run shell commands on remote machine") it fails:

**2018-12-14T17:59:52.0234815Z ##[error]bash: docker: command not found**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need this because I want to deploy my distributed app into docker(environment-based subnetwork).

So, on release, I use "Securely copy files to the remote machine" job to copy build artefacts. After that, I need to build a Docker image with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added "sudo" and the access rights("sudo visudo"):
sstcvetkov ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 1):

You have to be in the Docker Group or use sudo to run Docker commands.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```